# 2 column form layout with bootstrap 3 and a colspan

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a form with two column form layout. There should be a single row below the two columns (like colspan = 2 as in plain HTML table).

```
This design should not use table-reponsive and should be based solely on the form-horizontal, form-group and row, col-md-*, col-md-push-*, col-md-pull-* etc.

 I am facing the problem with aligning the row with two cols below with the above rows with 4 cols.
```

[A snapshot of the code run in jsfiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye4FJ.jpg)

The jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/Kamalika/sLyu52rg/

I am using bootstrap 3

The markup is as follows

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<div class="form-horizontal">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputDepartment" class="col-md-4 control-label">Department:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDept" placeholder="Department">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-10">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-1 control-label">ABCD:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                       <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea">default text</textarea>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have gone through some of the topics here and outside this forum. Unfortunately I could not make them work with the required criteria.

The criteria is :

The controls and the labels should be horizontal. Like this

Name : [Textbox]       Department: [Textbox]
ABCD : [Textarea]

But I am getting this

Name : [Textbox]       Department: [Textbox]
    ABCD : [Textarea]

I am having hard time to align ABCD label and the textarea with the above row.

I am new to bootstrap and html 5 and require help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Update
@vanburen - Sorry for the late reply. Hi, I tried out your solution. The form that i wanted to design is like this, please check out the jsfiddle give below your answer (the link is the same but it has /3 at end). I am having these problems now: 
1. some divs are overlapping the previous dropdownlist in a row, so some area is not clickable (here ii have used html selects, label and input text, but in practice am using the @Html.DropdownList, @Html.TextBoxFor, @Html.Label and @Html.TextAreaFor) 
2. the text area is again creating problem along with the buttons, need to have the text area stretched out till the margin of the end of the above controls and the buttons aligned withe the end of the text area on right

I had to put row divs, otherwise the textboxes or the dropdowns were not clickable.

I also need to reduce space between the label and control. Also I am using container-fluid.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your HTML structure. You don't need the `col-lg-4` and `col-lg-10` and your `textarea` should be **label** > `col-md-2`, **textarea** > `col-md-10` so everything lines up correctly.

Also, this class `col-md-pull-1` doesn't exist in Bootstrap.

See working example.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name:</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="department" class="col-md-4 control-label">Department:</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="department" placeholder="Department">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="ABCD" class="col-md-2  control-label">ABCD:</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="ABCD" name="textarea">default text</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried out your solution. The form that i wanted to design is like this - [link]http://jsfiddle.net/Kamalika/sLyu52rg/3/

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your column class. Change like this. Also remove `col-md-pull-1`

```
               <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-md-2  control-label">ABCD:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                           <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea">default text</textarea>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```